# Filter equals elements in a DataGridView

Tags: c#, datagridview

I should only take some items.

The excel file schema is as follows

```
<ConfigRegolatori>
<Id>6</Id>
<Address>92</Address>
<Category>90</Category>
<Mode>TC_K</Mode>
<Model>Z4TC</Model>
<Name>KT6</Name>

<ConfigRegolatori>
<Id>7</Id>
<Address>7</Address>
<Category>100</Category>
<Mode>TC_K</Mode>
<Model>M9_Servo</Model>
<Name>KT7</Name>

<ConfigRegolatori>
<Id>8</Id>
<Address>92</Address>
<Category>90</Category>
<Mode>TC_K</Mode>
<Model>Z4TC</Model>
<Name>KT10</Name>
```

The code part is the following

```
dtConfReg = new DataTable();
dtConfReg.ReadXml(Principale.strPathConfig + "\\ConfigRegulators.xml");
dtConfReg.TableName = "ConfigReg";

bsouReg = new BindingSource();
bsouReg.DataSource = dtConfReg;
dgvwConfigReg.DataSource = bsouReg;
```

Since I have multiple rows with the same value in the Address field, I would like to get a row for each value. For example, I have multiple records with the Address tag at 92, I just want to extract one.

PS: An important information is that I'm using the framework 2.0

Thanks

Comment: Why not doing it after you read the xml and before you set the `DataSource` and setting the modified list without multiple records as `DataContext`?

Comment: Try following : DataTable newTable = dtConfReg.AsEnumerable().GroupBy(x => x.Field<string>("Address")).Select(x => x.FirstOrDefault()).CopyToDataTable();

Comment: Gouping can not be done after DataSource assignment, you have to filter data in Linq before Assigning to Grid

Comment: Meanwhile, thank you for your answers.
The jdweng suggestion after which line of code should i put it in?

Comment: Sorry but the important information I did not say is that I'm working with framework 2.0

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `DefaultView` property of the `DataTable`.

```
dtConfReg.DefaultView.RowFilter = "Address = '92'";
```

The complete solution would be:

```
dtConfReg = new DataTable();
dtConfReg.ReadXml(Principale.strPathConfig + "\\ConfigRegulators.xml");
dtConfReg.TableName = "ConfigReg";
dtConfReg.DefaultView.RowFilter = "Address = '92'";

bsouReg = new BindingSource();
bsouReg.DataSource = dtConfReg.DefaultView;
dgvwConfigReg.DataSource = bsouReg;
```

Note that the filter is using single quotes for the value, don't use them if the value deserialized from XML is int.

**UPDATE**

I've changed the code to filter by that address. This solution works if you want to filter the data by some columns values.

If you want to get the distinct values from that XML, then I suggest you first get the values from XML and then use your existing code to bind the data table to the UI control.

Comment: I've tried your solution but it does not change anything.
In most, I explained badly, since I would like to take a tag for each different address.
That is, if I find address 90 I take an element, if I find address 93 I take the element but in case I encounter address 90 again I do not take it since I took it first.

Comment: Sorry but not being very experienced in C # and not knowing very well the English I did not understand your last sentence or what solution I recommend to use.